# ggplot2: connecting lines between dots from different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's some example code of the problem I'm having:

```
set.seed(1)
group1 <- sample(c(1, 0), size=200, replace=T)
group2 <- sample(c(1, 0), size=200, replace=T)
score <- rnorm(200) + .5*group1 + 2.2*group2 - 1.7*group1*group2
d <- data.frame(score=score, group1=as.factor(group1), group2=as.factor(group2))
k <- d %>% 
  group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(score), median=median(score))
k <- gather(k, "estimate", "value", mean, median)
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=group1, y=score, colour=group2)) + 
    geom_jitter(alpha = .3) +
    geom_point(data=k, aes(y=value, shape=estimate), size=3, position=position_dodge(width=.2))
```

Which produces this graphic:

[image: ggplot image]

So far so good. Now when I try to connect the lines as I need them:

```
p + geom_line(data=k, aes(y=value, linetype=estimate, group=estimate))
```

I get an error:

```
Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

I've seen other solutions online about connecting them, but these all assume the user is using the same datasets for both the base aes as well as the geom_line. Here, they are different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I should have waited five minutes before posting. I figured it out:

```
group1 = sample(c(1, 0), size=200, replace=T)
group2 = sample(c(1, 0), size=200, replace=T)
score = rnorm(200) + .5*group1 + 2.2*group2 - 1.7*group1*group2
d = data.frame(score=score, group1=as.factor(group1), group2=as.factor(group2))
k = d%>%group_by(group1, group2)%>%summarize(mean=mean(score), median=median(score))
k = gather(k, "estimate", "value", mean, median)
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=group1, y=score, colour=group2)) + 
    geom_jitter(alpha = .3) +
    geom_point(data=k, aes(y=value, shape=estimate), size=3, position=position_dodge(width=.2)) +
    geom_line(data=k, aes(y=value, linetype=estimate, group=interaction(group2,estimate)), position=position_dodge(width=.2))
```

Which produces:

[image]

I saw others post about the `interaction` function, but I was thinking about blending the variables between the two datasets; I didn't think that the second dataset had the same variable.

Hope this helps some weary traveler in the future!